# Delete all content of input text, without @bind in Blazor

Tags: c#, input, text, blazor, blazorise

I would like to know if it is possible to delete everything that the user has entered in the input text controls, using C# in Blazor, but without the controls being binded.

I have several text input but without @bind, so I cannot delete variables associated with @bind

Is it possible to do something like a "for" through the controls, and ask if it is of the input text type to delete its content?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using `@bind`?  That is how you are supposed to do it in Blazor.  Otherwise you're going to have to resort to messy JS interop, which defeats the purpose.  I'd advise you to figure out how to do this idiomatically, and we can certainly help with that.

Comment: The thing is i'm using a component, Blazorise DataGrid, and that grid has filters input texts. I need delete all filters with an external button, out of that component. The Id's of input texts coud be random all the time.

Answer (score 2):

So in a situation like this where you are using an extension, it's probably best to look at how the extension is implemented and work out a solution from there.  If you [examine the source code](https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise/blob/93c016408b7a0f12b9014c6fc7dcdd779f8cbf6c/Source/Extensions/Blazorise.DataGrid/DataGrid.razor#L82), you will see that the text box for the filter that you want to clear is bound to `column.Filter.SearchValue`:

```
<TextEdit Text="@column.Filter.SearchValue" TextChanged="@(async (newValue) => await OnFilterChanged(column, newValue))" />
```

From there, it's just a matter of being able to clear out that property *in C#*.  Unfortunately, Blazorise does not support public access to its `DisplayableColumns` property -- you need that in order to manipulate `SearchValue`.  One hacky workaround would be to subclass the `DataGrid`, since the property is `protected`:

```
public class MyDataGrid<TItem> : DataGrid<TItem>
{
    public IEnumerable<DataGridColumn<TItem>> MyColumns => DisplayableColumns;
}
```

With that, it's trivial to implement a "Clear Filters" button that clears all the filters.

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Filters" @onclick="ClearFilters" />
```

Implemented as:

```
private void ClearFilters() 
{
    foreach (var column in dataGrid.MyColumns)
    {
        column.Filter.SearchValue = null;
    }
}
```

You also need to capture the DataGrid in a field:

```
private MyDataGrid<Person> dataGrid;
```

For that field to be set, you need to add `@ref="dataGrid"` to your grid.

Now, all that said, it's pretty clear that having to create a subclass is suboptimal.  I've taken the liberty of [opening an issue](https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise/issues/1915) in [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise) and referenced this answer as a workaround.

The full example sans the subclass is:

```
<MyDataGrid TItem="Person" Data="@persons" Filterable="true" @ref="dataGrid">
    <DataGridColumn TItem="Person" Field="@nameof(Person.Name)" />
</MyDataGrid>

<input type="button" value="Clear Filters" @onclick="ClearFilters" />

@code {
    private MyDataGrid<Person> dataGrid;

    private void ClearFilters() 
    {
        foreach (var column in dataGrid.MyColumns)
        {
            column.Filter.SearchValue = null;
        }
    }

    private Person[] persons = new[]
    {
        new Person { Name = "John Doe" },
        new Person { Name = "Jane Down" }
    };

    public class Person 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note that due to an apparent limitation in Blazor, you will need to declare `MyDataGrid` in a separate file, and not as a class defined in a `@code` block.